# maven-glassfish-plugin in maven-3.0.4

Tags: maven-3, glassfish-2.x, maven-glassfish-plugin

Upon running `mvn install glassfish:deploy` I run into the following problems

```
[...]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project post-build-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:deploy failed: Plugin o    rg.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:jar:2.1 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0-SONATYPE-688946: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:9-SNAPSHOT in http://maven-repository/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of internal-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[...]
```

My `mvn -v` looks like this:

`Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: C:\Users\rob\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Futhermore my nexus-repository runs on `http://maven-repository` .

EDIT: The plugin-part from pom.xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <user>admin</user>
        <adminPassword>adminadmin</adminPassword>
        <glassfishDirectory>c:\development\glassfish-v2.1.1-b31g</glassfishDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Could you post post-build-pom.pom please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not the only one facing problems there :)

there seems to be even official bug report for that: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14411

As a workaround suggested here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4843
you should override the plugin dependencies in your project with proper versions.

Following should solve your problem:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <user>admin</user>
                <adminPassword>adminadmin</adminPassword>
                <glassfishDirectory>c:\development\glassfish-v2.1.1-b31g</glassfishDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Of course you need to provide all the configuration required, but it's another topic covered by: http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/examples/complete.html

Comment: just for the others that might won't find this place, I added the workaround to the official bug report as well :)

Comment: Hi Peter, many thanks for your answer. I reconfigured my project with the help of the supplied information and it simply works now.

Answer (score 2):

I find another way to solve this:

1. copy file "C:\Users\< current user >\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\11\maven-parent-11.pom"
   to
   "C:\Users\< current user >\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\11-SNAPSHOT\"
2. and rename it to "maven-parent-11-SNAPSHOT.pom"

Comment: Interesting approach; will test this soon.